# AOP expression problem

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I need to do few things before any method on `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` getting called. Hence I'm using an expression

`@Around("execution. (*org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.*(..)")`.

But I get an exception saying that

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating beanwithname 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'name pattern' at character position 80.
```

Could you please tell me  what is that I'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There needs to be a space character between the * and org.springframework.orm.jpa...

The beginning * is the wildcard for the return type of the method.

Comment: getting message Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting ')' at character position 0 . Now the expression is @Around("execution(* org.springframework. orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.*(..)")

Comment: @Around("execution(* org.springframework.orm.jpa. LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.*(..)")

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but any idea why its failing still ?

Comment: Mising a ) at the end. So it should be LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.*(..))

Comment: "Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut"

Comment: see http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?37817-error-at-0-formal-unbound-in-pointcut

Comment: Eve I bumbed into same thread. Resolved the issue. Thanks a lot.